# lesscss-maven-plugin not minifying properly

Tags: css, less

Before less compile i have the following css code in pages/dashboard.less

```
// main:../build/dashboard.less, compress: true, strictMath: true
#dash-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}
```

In build/dashboard.less I have the following code

```
// out: ../../css/dashboard.css, compress: true, strictMath: true
@import "common.less";
```

In my css/dashboard.css I have the following code when i am using brackets editor to compile less

```
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */ 
#dash-container{height:calc(100vh - 130px);}
```

But when I build using lesscss-maven-plugin I am getting the following css code. It is not a correct one. I am getting wrong compiled css. Can any one help me.

```
    #dash-container{height:calc(-30vh);}
```

Comment: You did not set `strictMath: true` for the plugin (assuming it has such option at all).

Answer (score 2):

You should add the same compilation arguments to `lesscss-maven-plugin` configuration. The official [org.lesscss:lesscss-maven-plugin](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin) does not support custom parameters, but you can use alternative plugin [biz.gabrys.maven.plugins:lesscss-maven-plugin](http://lesscss-maven-plugin.projects.gabrys.biz/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>biz.gabrys.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-lesscss</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <compress>true</compress>
                    <compilerOptions>
                        <compilerOption>--strict-math=on</compilerOption>
                    </compilerOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```